# Issues with creating second activity

Tags: java, android

I have run the app and written some text into it and pressed send. This is supposed to output "Hello World!" but instead the app just crashes every time. If there is anything else I can provide I can do so. This is my first time learning to code so I'm not aware where i could be going wrong. Thank you!

This is my MyActivity.java:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "anatol.healthygaming.MESSAGE";
/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);

}



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_my, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

This is my DisplayMessageActivity.java:

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Get the message from the intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MyActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    // Create the text view
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    // Set the text view as the activity layout
    setContentView(textView);
}



@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

It says that it was caused by:

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
```

Activity_my :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<EditText android.id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send"
    android:onClick="sendMessage"/>
```

Activity_display_message:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="anatol.healthygaming.DisplayMessageActivity">

<TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: Show the android manifest file and the xml files files of the activities please.

Comment: show your layout file `activity_my`

Comment: Added the activity_my

Comment: @AnatolGasiorowski in the <code>EditText</code> in the activity_my.xml, it should be android:id and not android.id

Comment: That was it Kritixi thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `EditText` in the `activity_my.xml` file has a `android.id`. Change it to `android:id` and it should solve your problem.

Reason:
Because `android.id` is invalid in android-xml, the `EditText` has no id. When you had
`EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);`
in the `MyActivity.java`, the compiler was not able to find `R.id.edit_message` because it did not exist, so `editText` was given the value of `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes apart from what Kritixi Lithos told you should also include your activity in Android Manifest file if you have not.